Bring Tshirts from Japan to American convention
I am going to America in at the end of the year for a convention. I am planning to bring original Tshirts from my shop to see there in baggage, maybe about 50 pieces or so.
Is there something I need to do before going there?
In formation is very hard to find.... It seems I have to declare commercial goods on a declaration form on the plane.
Do I need to pay tax? If so, how much?
Please help.
Thank you in advance from Japan.

"to see there": do you mean "sell"?

Legally speaking, as a visitor to the US, you can bring samples to exhibit at a convention, but you cannot sell them. So unless you have a suitable work visa, your plan is unfortunately not legal even if you pay Customs duties on the shirts.
That said, as a visitor to the US, you are entitled to a $100 (~¥15,000) duty-free exemption for "personal or household use".  If your T-shirts are worth less than this, you can legally import them and hand them out to friends, including people you meet at the convention, as souvenirs from Japan.
Alternatively, you can declare the T-shirts as business samples and either pay duty or post a temporary import bond, which you can claim back if/when you leave with the shirts. This way, you can legally exhibit or hand them out as samples at a convention, and then accept online orders in your Japanese online shop.  However, this would involve a lot of complicated paperwork, and I suspect that if you approach Customs and try to do this for a few dozen T-shirts, they will just wave you on.
Now maybe if you go to the convention and give people shirts, maybe they like them so much that they give you money in exchange.  That would be illegal, so I can't advise you to do that — but it's very unlikely anybody would care or that you would get into trouble.

The $800 duty-free allowance is for returning residents (despite the fact the page is under “international visitors”). The allowance is only $100 for visitors (see form 6059B https://www.cbp.gov/sites/default/files/2024-07/cbp_form_6059b_english_0.pdf)

@jcaron Thanks, corrected!

One option is to find a US friend who can act as a reseller for you. They can import the shirts from you (probably best to ship them separately to avoid arousing suspicion), sell them at the convention for a small markup, and it would be all above board. That you also happen to be at the convention at the same time is immaterial.
